# How to undo ./configure command

Tags: makefile, configure, libxml2

Is there a command that removes all the files created by the ./configure command of libxml2??

Thanks
Samuel

Answer (score 3):

try `make clean` or `make distclean`

or just re-run `./configure`, if the problem is that you ran it with the wrong switches previously.

Answer (score 0):

Untar libxml2 again!

Answer (score 0):

```
make confclean
```

When I configured Qt, this is the command suggested from the terminal to undo the configuration. It worked on my system: with GNU Make 3.81 built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0.

Otherwise, less elegant solution, you can erase the folder and start again.